# Clear last bash command from history from executing bash script

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, expect, password-protection

I have a bash script, which uses [expect](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index) package to `ssh` into a remote server.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "p:" option; do
   case "${option}" in
      p) PASSWORD=${OPTARG};;
   esac
done

/usr/bin/expect -c "

spawn ssh my.login.server.com
expect {
   \"Password*\" { 
     send \"$PASSWORD\r\" 
   }
 }
interact
"
```

I run it like ***`./login.sh -p <my-confidential-password>`***

Now once you run it and log in successfully and exit from the remote server, I can hit `up-arrow-key` from the keyboard and can still see my command with password in the terminal. Or I simply run `history` it shows up. Once I exit the terminal, then it also appears in `bash_history`.

I need something within my script that could clear it from history and leave no trace of the command I ran (or password) anywhere.

I have tried:

- Clearing it using `history -c && history -r`, this doesn't work as the script creates its own session.
- Also, `echo $HISTCMD` returns 1 within script, hence I cannot clear using `history -d <tag>`.

P.S. I am using macOS

Answer (score 4):

You could disable command history for a command:

```sh
set +o history
echo "$PASSWORD"
set -o history
```

Or, if your [`HISTCONTROL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTCONTROL) Bash variable includes `ignorespace`, you can indent the command with a space and it won't be added to the history:

```
$ HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
$ echo "Hi"
Hi
$  echo "Invisible"  # Extra leading space!
Invisible
$ history | tail -n2
    7  echo "Hi"
    8  history | tail -n2
```

Notice that this isn't secure, either: the password would still be visible in any place showing running processes (such as `top` and friends). Consider reading it from a file with `400` permissions, or use something like [`pass`](https://www.passwordstore.org/).

You could also wrap the call into a helper function that prompts for the password, so the call containing the password wouldn't make it into command history:

```sh
runwithpw() {
    IFS= read -rp 'Password: ' pass
    ./login.sh -p "$pass"
}
```